# Flow_from_dataframe - number of classes differs from actual number of classes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, keras, label

I'm using pandas to make use of the .txt file and flow_from_dataframe to help me read in the images from the folders.

This is my code:

```
import keras
import pandas as pd 
from keras_preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

data = pd.read_csv('/directory/clipart_train.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
data.columns = ["id", "labels"]

print(data)
print(data["id"].shape)
print(data["labels"].shape)

data["labels"] = data["labels"].astype('str')
print(data["labels"].dtype)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe = data,
        directory = "/directory/",
        x_col = "id",
        y_col = "labels",
        target_size=(224,224),
        class_mode = 'categorical',
        batch_size = 1
        )
```

I get the following format: [11372 rows x 2 columns] and the print command shows 'labels' ranging from 0 to 204.

But Flow_from_dataframe yields 'Found 11372 images belonging to 181 classes.' instead of 205 classes. Am I missing something?

edit: Problem does not occur on validation data with similar code (Found 1954 images belonging to 204 classes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dataset seems to be splitted by keras and keras internally does build a mapping. If you don´t pass the `classes` param, while the mapping is built it takes all the uinque classes present in the data and creates the mapping itself. If some classes are missing, they are missing in the mapping later on.

So the solution is to pass the list of your classes and you will be fine:

> classes: optional list of classes (e.g. ['dogs', 'cats']). Default:
>   None. If not provided, the list of classes will be automatically
>   inferred from the y_col, which will map to the label indices, will be
>   alphanumeric). The dictionary containing the mapping from class names
>   to class indices can be obtained via the attribute class_indices.

Not that missing classes in the training data, can not be predicted, as you classifier has no examples to learn from.